# Symfony: sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox() "on" vs true for Doctrine form?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, symfony-forms

I have a custom Form I've made that extends the Doctrine base forms for a Doctrine object.

I have a database field that is type: boolean. For my form, I have this represented by a `sfWidgetFormInputCheckbox()` widget. When my form is submitted, the value of my checkbox comes back as `on` if it was checked and if it wasn't checked, then no value is passed. Either way, when I do my `$form->save()`, the boolean field is not affected. Symfony/Doctrine wants to see a `true` or `false`. Not a `on` or no value at all.

My solution is just to see if the value was passed at all and if so, then that field is `true` else `false`:

```
$values['my_field'] = isset($values['my_field']) ? true : false;
```

Is this the proper way to handle this? I would think that Symfony/Doctrine would already understand how to handle checkboxes. I would expect it to know that if the value for the checkbox comes back as `on` then to set that value in the database as `true` and if it doesn't exist, then it's `false`.

Obviously my approach works... but what is the CORRECT approach?

Comment: Why dont you extend the form where 'my_field' is part of?

Comment: I did. When submitting the form, the value is "ON". Not "True" or "False".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sfValidatorBoolean` returns true or false. If you are not getting true or false after binding the form, you are not using this validator.

Comment: Ah interesting... I will have to try this. I did not know I needed to add this Validator since a checkbox can already only be true or false. I didn't know it would actually alter the passed value of the checkbox. Thanks a bunch!